# how to return content and then return a url in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to return the Content and then redirect to the url. how do i do this?

```
 public ActionResult ChangePasswordError()
    {
        Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Try Again!');</script>");
        return Redirect("https://localhost:76301/#!/manage");
    }
```

Comment: You can return page with js alert, and after clicking OK you can redirect from the page whatever you want. I dont think it is possible to return two actions (alert and redirect from one ActionResult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a header like this header( "refresh:10;url=newurl" );
And then your html with the script tag and the alert. Note that 10 is the number of seconds and newurl the redirected_url